# How to create a Dutch Book?

Tags: probability, logic

I found this question from [Ian Hacking's book on induction and probability](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521775019). I understand that a Dutch Book is a gambling term wherein everyone wins. Although, the last part of the question 'Describe a Dutch Book for Dave' is confusing. How is this prediction one where everyone wins?

> Dave thinks that the probability of an early Spring if Wiarton Willie
>   predicts an Early Spring is 4/5, but that the probability of not
>   having an early Spring if Wiarton Willie predicts an Early Spring is
>   2/5. Describe a Dutch Book for Dave.

Comment: If you offer Dave a bet on an early spring at $100$ to win $125$, and a late spring at $50$ to win $125$, then you'll make $150$ on the two bets and pay out $125$.  That's right at the threshold, so you could sweeten the payout to anywhere between $125$ and $150$.

Comment: A Dutch Book, as I understand it, is a book plus a set of bets where every *outcome* is a win for the bookie—not one where everyone wins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dave has managed to create a scenario in which he thinks if WW predicts an Early Spring, something will happen with a probability of $\frac65\gt1$.

This scenario is called a [Dutch book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_book) - everybody knows that the maximum sum of probabilities can only be $1$, but the odds offered don't match with this, and hence there is a guaranteed profit for someone.

Let's assume WW predicts an Early Spring, Dave has two decisions, to go with WW or to reject WW's guess.

So Dave places £100 on both events at the odds he **thinks** he will get, but his mistake is in the way he calculated the odds. Elementary analysis reveals Dave's mistake:

A percentage $p\%$ to win equals $\frac1{1+w}$ where $w$ are the odds offered.

So $0.8=\frac1{1+w}\to1+w=\frac54\to 4w=1\to w=0.25$ and this gives odds of $4$ to $1$ on (stake £1, return £1.25).

And, $0.4=\frac1{1+w}\to1+w=\frac52\to 2w=3\to w=1.5$ and this gives odds of $3$ to $2$ against (stake £1, return £2.50).

An obvious scenario would be $P(\text{no Early Spring|WW says ES})=0.2$:

And, $0.2=\frac1{1+w}\to1+w=5\to w=4$ and this gives odds of $4$ to $1$ against (stake £1, return £5.00).

So Dave's on a loser because if he had correctly evaluated the probabilities, he could have got much better odds.